# Whitespace On Top of Div When Resizing Window

Tags: html, css

I currently have two inline-block `div` in my post page that contain my most recent book reviews. For most window sizes, these sections match up and take the same amount of space. For some windows dimensions, however, one `inline-block` takes up less space than the other, causing there to be white space at the bottom of the smaller div.

Is there anything I can do to get rid of this whitespace?

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.newest-review-cover {
  z-index: 0;

}

.newest-review-cover img {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;


}

.newest-review-content h2 {
 
 color: white;
 font-size: 2rem;
 padding-top: 1em;
}

.newest-review-content h5 {
 padding: 1em 3em;
 color: white;
 font-size: 1rem;

}

.newest-review-content {
 background-color: black;
 padding: 2em 0;
 text-align: center;

}





.book-review img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;

  


}



.book-review {
 background-color: black;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 33%;
 padding-left: 0;
 border-right: solid 3px #f28600;
 border-left: solid 3px #f28600;
 border-top: solid 5px #f28600;
 margin-left: -4px;
 margin-top: 0;

 vertical-align: top;




}

.book-review p {
 color: white;
 margin: 1em 0;
}

.post-title {
 text-align: center;
 
}



.post-description {
 padding: 0 2em;
 height: 100px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head> 
 <link href="header+footer.css" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="Homepage.css" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title> The Novel Column - Book Reviews </title>

</head>
 

<body>

<nav>

 <h1> <a href="index.html"> The Novel Column </a> </h1>

 <ul>
  <li> <a href="#"> Resources </a>
   <ul> 
    <li> <a href="#"> Book Reviews </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Quotes and Principles </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Community Aid </a> </li>
    
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#"> About Us </a> </li>
 </ul>
 
</nav>

<section class="newest-review-cover"> 
 <img src="images/the-5am-club-poster.jpg" alt="The 5AM Club">

 <div class="newest-review-content"> 
  <h2> The 5AM Club Review </h2>
  <h5> Maximize your productivity, be around nice things, and spend more time doing what you want! </h5>
 </div>
</section>

<div class="all-posts"> 
 <a href="the-one-thing.html">
 <div class="book-review" id="the-one-thing"> 
  <img src="https://thenovelcolumn.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/The-ONE-Thing-Image-3.jpg" alt="The ONE Thing">

  <div class="book-description">
  <p class="post-title"> The ONE Thing Review </p>
  <p class="post-description"> Declutter your life, think big, and achieve mastery!</p>
  </div>

 </div>
 </a>

 <a href="the-10x-rule.html">
 <div class="book-review" id="the-10x-rule">
  <img src="https://thenovelcolumn.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/The-10X-Rule-Image-2-e1555476700855.jpg" alt="The 10X Rule" alt="The 10X Rule">

  <div class="book-description">
  <p class="post-title"> The 10X Rule Review </p>
  <p class="post-description"> Unlock your potential and multiply happiness and productivity!</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</a>
 
</div>



</body>




</html>
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies with .post-description

If you look at your .post-description for both blocks, their text have different height.

You can set a fix height to .post-description and set `vertical-align: top;` to .book-review

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.newest-review-cover {
  z-index: 0;

}

.newest-review-cover img {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;


}

.newest-review-content h2 {
 
 color: white;
 font-size: 2rem;
 padding-top: 1em;
}

.newest-review-content h5 {
 padding: 1em 3em;
 color: white;
 font-size: 1rem;

}

.newest-review-content {
 background-color: black;
 padding: 2em 0;
 text-align: center;

}





.book-review img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;

  


}



.book-review {
 background-color: black;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 33%;
 padding-left: 0;
 border-right: solid 3px #f28600;
 border-left: solid 3px #f28600;
 border-top: solid 5px #f28600;
 margin-left: -4px;
 margin-top: 0;

  vertical-align: top; /*Added this to set alignment to top*/


}

.book-review p {
 color: white;
 margin: 1em 0;
}

.post-title {
 text-align: center;
  
}



.post-description {
 padding: 0 2em;
    height: 150px; /*Added a fixed height*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head> 
 <link href="header+footer.css" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="Homepage.css" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title> The Novel Column - Book Reviews </title>

</head>
 

<body>

<nav>

 <h1> <a href="index.html"> The Novel Column </a> </h1>

 <ul>
  <li> <a href="#"> Resources </a>
   <ul> 
    <li> <a href="#"> Book Reviews </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Quotes and Principles </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Community Aid </a> </li>
    
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#"> About Us </a> </li>
 </ul>
 
</nav>

<section class="newest-review-cover"> 
 <img src="images/the-5am-club-poster.jpg" alt="The 5AM Club">

 <div class="newest-review-content"> 
  <h2> The 5AM Club Review </h2>
  <h5> Maximize your productivity, be around nice things, and spend more time doing what you want! </h5>
 </div>
</section>

<div class="all-posts"> 
 <div class="book-review" id="the-one-thing"> 
  <img src="https://thenovelcolumn.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/The-ONE-Thing-Image-3.jpg" alt="The ONE Thing">

  <div class="book-description">
  <p class="post-title"> The ONE Thing Review </p>
  <p class="post-description"> Declutter your life, think big, and achieve mastery!</p>
  </div>

 </div>
 
 <a href="the-10x-rule.html">
 <div class="book-review" id="the-10x-rule">
  <img src="https://thenovelcolumn.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/The-10X-Rule-Image-2-e1555476700855.jpg" alt="The 10X Rule">

  <div class="book-description">
  <p class="post-title"> The 10X Rule Review </p>
  <p class="post-description"> Unlock your potential and multiply happiness and productivity!</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</a>
 
</div>



</body>




</html>
```

Comment: When I use a set value for height, the majority of window sizes work now! However, the second div height becomes shorter and white space appears at the bottom of the div. How would I eliminate this white space?

Comment: It could also be that some of your .post-title are of different height, you may want to fix a height for it as well